# Same algorithm runs differently in C and PHP

Tags: php, c

I was practicing a problem on CodeChef.com.

https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHOPRT --> Link to the question I was solving.

I successfully solved the question using C.

My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int t;
    int num1;
    int num2;


    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--) {

        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
        if(num1 > num2)
            printf(">");
        else if(num1 < num2)
            printf("<");
        else
            printf("=");
        printf("\n");           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I am not able to solve it using PHP:

My PHP code:

```
<?php

    $t = intval(fgets(STDIN));

    while($t--) {

        $line = split(" ", trim(fgets(STDIN)));
        $num1 = intval($line[0]);
        $num2 = intval($line[1]);

        if($num1 < $num2)
            print("<");
        else if($num1 > $num2)
            print(">");
        else
            print("="); 
        print("\n");        
    }
?>
```

Though both the programs run perfectly on my MacBook Pro, the PHP code is not run on codechef.com and gives a `WA`(Wrong Answer). C code is run perfectly though and that to within 0.00 seconds.

Please, enlighten me with the difference between the two respective codes, which I personally believe, should be working the same, and also produce the same output.

Comment: What do you mean by "gives a `WA`"?

Comment: WA stands for Wrong Answer

Comment: @RocketHazmat: "Weird Algorithm"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `What A?`

Comment: Seems to work here: https://eval.in/438507

Comment: Yeah. It even works on my mac. But is not submitted on codechef. I even tried the same code in Python. So it gave me a runtime error while taking input and using `input().split(" ")` function. Whats under the scenes?

Comment: Maybe you have an extra newline or something that it doesn't like?  Maybe it's expecting the exit code of `0` (`exit(0)`)?

Comment: Many find the same problem with PHP and python. What should be done? They say they are successful with C and C++. But theres some problem with the input in PHP or python

Comment: Maybe you could ask them?  Could be a bug in their submission code.

Comment: No satisfactory response from their side. What am I doing wrong with PHP? I am just not able to figure out

Comment: Have you looked inside other submitter's codes? The ones who made it in PHP, to see if there is something different.

Comment: You have some space or newline after the `?>`.  You don't need the `?>` I would delete it.

Comment: No body did it in PHP. And No. I am pretty sure there no white space before or after the PHP tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often i hear that some testcases are erroneous.I have a corner case for you which would give perfect result for your C code but not for your PHP

Do this :

```
1
10  10
```

Notice there is more than one space between the two digits.

I tested it [here](https://eval.in/438522).
Instead of the expected output which is:

```
=
```

your Output is:

```
>
```

Though C would pass this test case as scanf searches for the next integer number you type, PHP would fail since there is more than one space.
To make it work in PHP i did suggest you to code in such a way that the spaces between the two numbers dont affect your expected output.

That's the only way i believe your PHP Code won't work.If this indeed was the issue it's not your fault!

Comment: This can be fixed in PHP by using [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf).  `sscanf(fgets(STDIN), '%d', $t);` and then `sscanf(fgets(STDIN), '%d %d', $num1, $num2);`.  See: https://eval.in/438547